# Triples $(p,q,r)$ of primes satisfying the quadratic residue relation $\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{q}{r}\right)=\left(\frac{p}{r}\right)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

I stumbled upon this problem while thinking about quadratic residues:

> Find all triples $(p,q,r)$ of primes such that 
>   $$\genfrac(){}{0}{p}{q}\cdot\genfrac(){}{0}{q}{r} = \genfrac(){}{0}{p}{r}$$

I didn't make much progress beyond some trivial observations.

Comment: Aren't there infinitely many?

Comment: Is $p=q=r$ a "trivial observation"? What else did you find?

Answer (score 1):

One can demonstrate infinitely many solutions as follows:-

Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct primes congruent to $3$ modulo $4$. Then $\genfrac(){}{0}{p}{q}$ and $\genfrac(){}{0}{q}{p}$ have opposite signs.

Therefore, for any other odd prime $r$, precisely one of $(p,q,r)$ and $(q,p,r)$ satisfies your rule.